# svn diff between previous and new working copy

Tags: svn, diff

suppose that I have made some changes since last update (revert) to my a.b file.
this a.b file is also changed in the repository.
Now I want to compare the changes I made with the repos changes.

If I svn revert the file, I can see the changes between new and previous download (previous download doesn't have my changes). How can I see differences between the repository changes and mine?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> svn diff -r HEAD a.b

I think you have to specify the HEAD revision if something changes in the repository.

But now that I re-read your question, it looks like you:
  made a change
  committed the change
  now want to view those changes

In that case, you can get your current revision number with

> svn info a.b

subtract 1 from it, and use it in the svn diff.

for example, if your current revision is 100

> svn diff -r 99:100

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Subclipse in Eclipse it will mark the file as conflict and when you double click on the conflicting file, it will show you on the one side your local file and on the right side the repositiry file.

The conflicts are marked red, and you can easily assume the changes or mark as merged.

For more information : http://subclipse.tigris.org/